# How to align images with embedded maps in HTML?

Tags: html, css, layout

I want to get all 4 images in line with the map embedded at the bottom of my page. Instead, I am getting the images below my map:

[image: screenshot of issue]

Can anyone help?

Here is my code.

HTML:

```html
<div class="map">
    <div class="gmap">
        <iframe width="600" height="600" id="gmap"
            src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=pharmacy&t=&z=13&ie=UTF8&iwloc=&output=embed" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="online">
    <p>Online Orders: </p>
    <a href="https://www.1mg.com/" target="_blank"><img src="resources/images/1mg.png" height="100" width="100"> 1mg</a>
    <a href="https://www.medlife.com/" target="_blank"><img src="resources/images/Medlife.png" height="100" width="100"> Medlife</a>
    <a href="https://pharmeasy.in/" target="_blank"><img src="resources/images/Pharmeasy.png" height="100" width="100"> Pharmeasy</a>
    <a href="https://www.netmeds.com/" target="_blank"><img src="resources/images/Netmeds.png" height="100" width="100"> Netmeds</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
} 
a{
  text-decoration: none;
}
    
.online{
  display: inline-flex;
  text-align: justify;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0px 650px;
}

img{
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just putting `float` as left for gmap would do the job. You can set the margin and padding of the images as per your likings. The below code aligns them right beside the map

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#gmap {
  float: left;
}

.online {
  padding-top: 475px;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="map">
  <div class="gmap">
    <iframe width="600" height="600" id="gmap" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=pharmacy&t=&z=13&ie=UTF8&iwloc=&output=embed" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="online">
  <p>Online Orders: </p>
  <a href="https://www.1mg.com/" target="_blank"><img src="resources/images/1mg.png" height="100" width="100"> 1mg</a>
  <a href="https://www.medlife.com/" target="_blank"><img src="resources/images/Medlife.png" height="100" width="100"> Medlife</a>
  <a href="https://pharmeasy.in/" target="_blank"><img src="resources/images/Pharmeasy.png" height="100" width="100"> Pharmeasy</a>
  <a href="https://www.netmeds.com/" target="_blank"><img src="resources/images/Netmeds.png" height="100" width="100"> Netmeds</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I want the logos to be adjacent to the map's '+' sign i.e I want them at bottom-right of my page and not on top

Comment: @AAGAMJAIN Then just add padding. I made the edit, check it